# The best way to design RESTFull API where a method is applicable to both the entity and the list?

Tags: rest

let's say we have a restful API that returns either a list of all books or an information about an individual book, i.e. something like this:

```
/books/{book_id}
```

Now, I need to define a "history" method that would return a history of the book requests. It's applicable to all books as well as an individual book.

What's the best way to design such the API?

Shall I allocate another resource i.e /history and then call it with a parameter that can be either book_id or "*all"
or add the history parameter to the existing book resource?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you exhausted the usual possibilities. As an api consumer, nether would surprise me.

Comment: Yes, but what would be a better way from the RESTFul paradigm perspective?

Comment: By my lights neither.  Just be consistent.  Arguably if you could act on the historical entities, it might make more sense to make them separate entities.